# How to get rid of already selected items in combobox

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, combobox, arraycollection

Am having an issue with combobox duplications
i have 10 autocomplete comboboxes with all having same dataprovider...
suppose like this array collection

```
public var costCenter:ArrayCollection = new
    ArrayCollection(["1101","1111","1121","1131","1141","1151", 
        "1161","1171","1181","1191"]);
```

if 1st combobox is selected with 1131 then that shouldnt be there in next comboboxes dataprovider.
that is already selected items should be removed from collection for dataprovider
and user can select 1st any of the 10 comboboxes

am making a copy of collection and using that collection as dataprovider for all comboboxes..
how to remove the already selected items from collection?
any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`filterFunction`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#filterFunction) on you `ArrayCollection` instances and call `refresh()` on them after selecting values. But all the collections should be different instances from the single `Array` as a source.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work properly since what would you be filtering exactly, which one is selected in *all* comboboxes?  What happens when the current combobox selects one and it gets filtered out? it would be removed from the combobox that just selected it...

Comment: I mean performing refreshing of all data providers on changing any combo box selection.

Comment: ah, that would work as long as he has a different filterFunction for each collection.

Comment: Yes. One `filterFunction` per collection.

Comment: what if it is xmllistcollection instead of array collection?

Comment: I suppose there shouldn't be any problem with different `XMLListCollection` initialized with the same `XMLList`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to remove the items from selectedIndices if you are doing version 3.x then you can just do something like `comboBox.selectedIndex = -1`, but in 4.x you have to do something like `comboBox.selectedIndices = new Vector.<int>()`.